# Node.js not connecting with mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, windows-phone-7, socket.io

I've been working on a small radio player that uses node.js to create a websocket that pushes through updates to the song and artist when an xml file is updated and it work great on all desktop browsers.However when I tried testing the it on my iPad and Windows Phone, Node.js doesn't connect or even acknowledge something trying to connect. What's causing this and how do I fix it? 
Please and Thank you

Server.js

```
app.listen(8080);
function handler(req, res) {
 fs.readFile(__dirname + '/wp-content/themes/c/page-player.php', function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
     console.log(err);
     res.writeHead(500);
     return res.end('Error loading index.php');
   }
   console.log("connection!");
   res.writeHead(200);
   res.end(data);
  });
}
```

Client.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var localURL = 'http://***.**.**.**:8080';
var socket = io.connect(localURL);// creating a new websocket
```

**Edit:** Forgot to metion: everything else on the page loads, just the websockets aren't connecting.

Comment: Aren't they even loading the index page, or aren't they connecting with websockets?

Comment: Sorry, I'll put this in the main question. Everything else on the page loads, just the websockets aren't connecting.